# Javascript how we can search if an id is duplicated in an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I need to check if an array contains duplicated values.

Lets say I have the following array of arrays:

```
array = [
  { id: 123, name: 'Emily', address: 'UK' },
  { id: 123, name: 'Ross', address: 'USA' },
  { id: 157, name: 'Joey', address: 'Italy' },
];
```

As you can see, I have 2 arrays, aving the same ID `id=123`, and I need to detect these 2 rows, so we can clean the data we have.

P.S. I am only interested in checking duplication on IDs and Names at the same time.

I did the following logic, but it doesn't make sense, as it returns rows more than the existed ones:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.array.forEach((row) => {
      this.array.find(element => {
        if (element['id'] === row['id']) {
          console.log(row)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

The output is like:

> 123 Emily
>
> 123 Emily
>
> 123 Ross
>
> 123 Ross
>
> 157 Joey

My needed out output is as the following:

> 123 Emily
>
> 123 Ross

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzbi1y).

Comment: That isn't an array of arrays. That's an array of objects.

Comment: There are [at least a dozen](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+find+duplicate+object+property) previous questions about finding duplicates of objects in arrays. Have you worked through their answers? This is an often-asked question that's bound to have been answered sufficiently in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and map like this to get a distinct-like behaviour:

```
function distinct(myArray, prop) {
    return myArray.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is an **often-asked** duplicate. It doesn't need more answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder cool down please. I didn't know the exact key words to search for this issue, so calm down man. feel free to down vote it to to close it. And Thanks Alex for the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just missed how to search for it. You notice that I have a reputation of 2,404, so I am not a newbie. Thanks for the duplicated possible questions, I am checking them. But I thought you are the one who down voted the question.

Comment: @alim1990 - Nope, not me. :-) It's often that way, one person comments and another downvotes. My bar for downvoting is fairly high.